# Python pandas: create data frame with key in one columna and value in another

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way write the content of dictionary shared below, in a pandas dataframe. I wish to generate dataframe and eventually write it an excel.

```
Format : 
  Aggregate.       Subnet
'10.109.0.0/16'.   '10.109.0.0/19', 
                   '10.109.32.0/19', 
                   '10.109.64.0/19', 
                   '10.109.96.0/19', 
                   '10.109.128.0/19', 
                   '10.109.160.0/19'





dic = {
'10.109.0.0/16': ['10.109.0.0/19', '10.109.32.0/19', '10.109.64.0/19', '10.109.96.0/19', '10.109.128.0/19', '10.109.160.0/19', '10.109.192.0/19', '10.109.224.0/19'],
'10.111.0.0/16': [
    '10.111.0.0/24',
    '10.111.0.0/19',
    '10.111.1.0/24',
    '10.111.32.0/19',
    '10.111.48.0/24',
    '10.111.64.0/20',
    '10.111.189.0/24',
    '10.111.190.0/24',
    '10.111.192.0/19',
    '10.111.224.0/19'
]
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One possible option :

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(
        [
            [k, e] for k,l in dic.items() for e in l
        ], columns = ["Aggregate", "Subnet"])
    .assign(Aggregate= lambda x: (s:=x["Aggregate"]).where(~s.duplicated(), ""))
    # .to_excel("file.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1", index=False) # uncomment if needed
)
```

Output :

```
        Aggregate           Subnet
0   10.109.0.0/16    10.109.0.0/19
1                   10.109.32.0/19
2                   10.109.64.0/19
3                   10.109.96.0/19
4                  10.109.128.0/19
5                  10.109.160.0/19
6                  10.109.192.0/19
7                  10.109.224.0/19
8   10.111.0.0/16    10.111.0.0/24
9                    10.111.0.0/19
10                   10.111.1.0/24
11                  10.111.32.0/19
12                  10.111.48.0/24
13                  10.111.64.0/20
14                 10.111.189.0/24
15                 10.111.190.0/24
16                 10.111.192.0/19
17                 10.111.224.0/19
```